# Network routing between mac & virtual XP

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vpn

I have a mac laptop running XP inside VirtualBox. The network is setup to be a "Bridged Adapter" so that the IPs for both the host & guest OS's are assigned by my wireless routed.

My guest XP has Nortel VPN connecting to corporate lan.  When this is connected, I want to allow my host Mac OS to access the corporate network. But I'm struggling.

Without Nortel VPN running, I can change routing on the mac so all traffic is sent via the guest XP - this works. But once I activate the VPN, this no longer works. If I try to change the routing on mac to run through the IP address assigned to the Nortel adapter, I get a "Network is unreachable" error.

Below is the output from ipconfig /all on the guest XP OS.

I'm beginning to believe that what I want to do is not possible because of the way Nortel secure the VPN - but before I give up I thought I'd post the problem here.

Thanks, Kevin

```
z:\eclipseworkspace\RESMobileSuite\trunk>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : zzzz-3177b42dd0
    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : zzzz.zzz

 Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : AMD PCNET Family PCI Ethernet Adapter
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-XX-XX-XX-XX
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 30 April 2010 12:22:02
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 01 May 2010 12:22:02

    Ethernet adapter {8EB7A442-9683-45FB-A602-56110A4B3434}:

    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : zzzz.zz
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Nortel IPSECSHM Adapter - Packet Scheduler Miniport

    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 44-45-YY-YY-YY-YY
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : XXX.4.52.62
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.254.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : XXX.4.52.62
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : XXX.6.21.36
                                        XXX.6.21.100
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Enable connection sharing on Windows XP interface
2. Add routing table entry on your MAC for your company network. I don't know Mac but it probably would be something along these lines:

   route add XXX.4.52.62 mask 255.255.254.0 192.168.1.3

Comment: Hi Kyrisu - as I understand things, to enable connection sharing on XP, I need to select two connections (displayed in the Network Connections list) and bridge them. The problem is that I only see the AMD ethernet adapter, not the Nortel adapter in this list.

Comment: I meant Right click on the connection -> Properties -> Sharing Tab , but maybe even better would be to enable routing http://www.home-network-help.com/ip-forwarding.html